# Executing final logic after a feature is created or changed

Tags: qgis, features

There is a function "Python Init function" which is called when the form is opened.

[image]

Is there a function that is called when the form is closed or saved?
Or is there another way to execute some logic after I create/edited a feature?

Because I want to update the geometry of a feature based on two fields (x,y) whenever the two fields are changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define the function in this script and connect it for example to the `buttonbox` with `OK` and `Cancel`. You also have to define some global variables... see this short example. It will connect the `buttonbox` from the dialog with the function (slot) doSomething. If you press OK for finishing the dialog the function `doSomething` will do your job:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QWidget

def doSomething():
    # here you can do somthing with myfeature
    # this will be done after pressing OK
    print("done")

def my_form_open(dialog, layer, feature):
    global myfeature
    myfeature = feature
    x = dialog.findChild(QWidget, "x") #lineEdit x
    y = dialog.findChild(QWidget, "y") #lineEdit y
    bb = dialog.findChild(QWidget, "buttonBox")
    bb.accepted.connect(doSomething) #this connects your function doSomething
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me to understand it much better!